# How does a STUN server behave when it receives request with same Transaction ID from diffrent STUN Agents?

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

When a STUN server receives a request from two different STUN Agents with the same Transaction ID, how should it behave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Transaction ID from the STUN binding request is simply echoed back in the STUN binding response.  The server doesn't attempt to interpret this value for anything other than perhaps logging.  Nor does it attempt to manage or handle duplicate requests or duplicate transaction IDs. If two different clients send a binding request with the same Transaction ID, then both will get the same Transaction ID in their corresponding response.

The Transaction ID is simply for the client's benefit.  If the client receives a response from the server with a different Transaction ID than what it used in the request, it should simply ignore it. As that packet could be a late arrival from a previous STUN session.

About the only time a duplicate transation ID can exist is when a client times out waiting for a response and resends the binding request again.  RFC 5389 alludes to this in [section 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389#section-6):  `Resends of the same request reuse the same transaction ID`.

Answer (score 1):

This should not happen, but if then server should check the 5-tuple (The combination of client IP address and port, server IP address and port, and transport protocol (currently one of UDP, TCP, or TLS)). If the 5-tuple mismatches then server should proceed considering that as a valid transaction, otherwise it should behave as per the RFC-5766.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you should prepare your software to handle such kind of weird situations. The transaction id is a random value generated by the clients and it is very unlikely that you will see such kind of bug in stun clients.

> The transaction ID is a 96-bit identifier, used to uniquely identify
>      STUN transactions.  For request/response transactions, the
>      transaction ID is chosen by the STUN client for the request and
>      echoed by the server in the response.

When not random, then most probably that will be caused by one single bogus client software, and eventually you just end up sending bad answers to that client until its developer find this and fix their software.

Comment: The transaction id is a 128-bit identifier. Isn't it?